# How to unescape non-standard characters in XML in Java?

Tags: java, xml, xml-parsing

I realize a similar question has been asked before, and the solution is to use [StringEscapeUtils.unescape()](http://commons.apache.org/lang/api-2.4/org/apache/commons/lang/StringEscapeUtils.html#unescapeXml%28java.lang.String%29). However, per the method description:

> Supports only the five basic XML
>   entities (gt, lt, quot, amp, apos).
>   Does not support DTDs or external
>   entities.

I have a bunch of XML files with escaped characters like `&blank;` and `&hyph;`. How can I unescape these? They are defined in the DTD provided. Is there a method like StringEscapeUtils but one with DTD support?

Answer (score 0):

Hmm, it's been a long time, but I think an implementation of `EntityResolver2` (Java SDK) handles externally defined entities. This is part of the SAX2 specification.